# how to sync Salesforce and iCloud

Tags: sync

I want to be Mac based and Salesforce synched, how can I achieve this? I use Mac Mail, iCloud and Salesforce, is there a onestop synching solution available, or what are the otter options available?

Comment: sync what excatly? contacts, emails, tasks, files ?

Comment: whatevs @superfell (contacts, emails, tasks, files would be a bonus)

Comment: So similar to how there's a Salesforce for Outlook plug-in for Windows, but for Mac?

Comment: Definitely not looking for Outlook plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across this sync tool, OneSync http://www.go1consulting.com/OneSync . It sync Mac Contacts, Task and Calendars as well as outlook for Mac with salesforce (and vice versa).No plugins or any installation on salesforce required.  It s worth to check it out !!