# what is the next best thing to sf3?

Tags: api, data-synchronization, mac-os-x

I am looking to sync my Mac with Salesforce, it seems that SF3 (SF Cubed was very popular) however it is no longer supported and is buggy on account of recent OS updates. What is the next best thing for synching salesforce with iCal and Mail?

Comment: Have you reviewed the comments here, [Support Apple / Mac apps on OS X (Mail, iCal, Address Book)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bpb3AAC)? Appears there are a few options, though nothing that's a replacement for SF3. Also, seems like you've asked this question before, "[How to sync Salesforce and iCloud?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20728/how-to-sync-salesforce-and-icloud)" - what has changed?

Answer (score 1):

what data are you looking to sync?

I'm guessing you mean contacts and calendar events.
If so, you could possibly (i'm not terribly familiar with this product) use Cirrus Insights gmail plugin as an intermediary between your mac and SF. Since your mac's built in mail.app and calendar.app can access gmail accounts, and Cirrus Insights integrates Gmail and SF, this might work.

Comment: this solution would be unsatisfactory as it requires me to have gmail, I would therefore need to log into gmail in order to do the synching, no? I would like to just use the OS X tools such as iCal and Mac Mail and Salesforce.